# How do integration tests on a very simple webpage in Flask

Tags: flask, integration-testing, jinja2

I my project has got a web interface that provides some functions from MyPackage Python module. Basically it is one page that is the same for all the routes. I do not even use a database here. Is there anything that could be tested?

```
class MyTextForm(FlaskForm):
    text_content = StringField('mytextfield', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(20, 30)], widget=TextArea())


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'], defaults={'sub': 'sub1'})
@app.route('/subpage/<sub>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index(subpage):
    form = TweetTextForm()
    prediction_results = dict()
    try:
        model = app.models[subpage]

        if form.validate_on_submit():
            result = model.process(request.form["text_content "])

        return render_template('template.html',
                               value1=value1,
                               value2=value2,
                               form=form,
                               data=model.get_data())
    except Exception:
        abort(404)
```

Should I also test jinja templates?
I am not really sure what should be tested there?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can test that your pages load and behave the way you expect them to using something like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). For instance, you would have Selenium open a browser, go to each of your url routes, and confirm that it is loading the elements correctly.

This won't test your visuals, but it will allow you to confirm that the backend and templates are doing what they are supposed to do.

You might have something like:

*integration_tests.py*

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

class PageLoadTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

    def test_main_page(self):
        self.driver.get('/subpage/sub')
        element_to_check = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('name_of_element_tag_you_want_to_check')
        self.assertEqual(element_to_check.text, 'text that should be there')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

You could then start your test server and call this from the shell to run the tests (using separate terminals):

Server terminal:

```
$ flask run
```

Command terminal:

```
$ python integration_tests.py
```

I'd also recommend adding and testing (both unit and integration/functional) some input validation/sanitization on your form elements and `<sub>` variables using [html_sanitizer](https://pypi.org/project/html-sanitizer/) and perhaps [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/BeautifulSoup/) to remove unwanted html and the like.